# Eliminar filas de un archivo CSV

Tags: php, csv

Estoy intentando insertar los registros de un archivo `CSV` que descargo a través de la web y quiero saber como puedo manipular las filas que están registradas en el archivo.

Ya descubrí como manipular las columnas, pero quisiera saber si alguien sabe como manipular las filas. Este es el código que tengo.

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
require "../../APIs/conexion.php";


/* URL desde dónde se hará la descarga del archivo en formato excel .csv */
$url =  "http://omawww.sat.gob.mx/cifras_sat/Documents/Listado_Completo_69-B.csv";

/* Inicializa la función para obtener el archivo de la URL */
$ch = curl_init($url);

/* Devuelve el resultado de la transferencia como string */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

/* Ejecuta la descarga del archivo desde la URL */
$output = curl_exec($ch);

/* Realiza el guardado del archivo con el nombre listasNegras.csv y se le da la propiedad de solo lectura con 'w' */
$fh = fopen('listasNegras.csv', 'w');

/* Verifica que el archivo se haya guardado correctamente en el mismo directorio donde se encuentra guardado descargaIncumplidos.php */
if(fwrite($fh, $output))
{
    echo "Guardado con exito!"; //Si fue guardado correctamente, manda un mensaje en pantalla
}
else
{
    echo "No guardado"; //De lo contrario, también manda un mensaje en pantalla
}

/* Comprueba la existencia del archivo descargado */
if(file_exists('listasNegras.csv'))
{
    echo "\n Existe\n";
    $fh = fopen('listasNegras.csv', 'r');
    $archivo = "listasNegras.csv";
    $file = file($archivo);
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($file as $lineaNum => $linea)
    {
        if ($i == 0)
        {
            $datos = explode(",", $linea);
            $numero = trim($datos[0]);
            echo $numero."\n";
        }
    }

}
else
{
    echo "\n no Existe";
}
/* Cierra el archivo creado listasNegras.csv */
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo veas ésta librería,https://csv.thephpleague.com/ saludos!.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo checaré!

Answer (score 1):

Tengo esta funcion de un anterior proyecto, quizas te pueda ayudar. Es de un txt, pero la funcionalidad seria la misma con un csv

```
function borrar_fila(){
$DELETE = $_POST["delete"];
$data = file("archivo.txt");
$out = array();
    foreach($data as $line) {
        if(trim($line) != $DELETE) {
            $out[] = $line;
         }
     }
```

```
if (isset ($_POST["delete"])) //BOTON eliminar
{borrar_fila();}
```